# HTML5 Geolocation: measures when not moving

Tags: html, geolocation

I have a web app that allows users to create a cardio  workout where they may or may not be actually moving.  They could create a "run" either outside or on a treadmill.  Either way, geolocation is automatically enabled for the workout.

But I only show the distance on the screen if they have moved at least .25 of a mile.  I have tested this myself and the problem is that geolocation is telling me I'm moving even when I'm not!

This evening I was on the eliptical machine for 32 minutes and my app told me I had moved 1.15 miles.

If I test the app when actually moving, (e.g. in a car, on a bike, etc.) geolocation works fine.  It's only when I'm NOT moving that I'm having problems.

Anyone else face this issue?  Is there perhaps a hack to prevent it?
I'm using Chrome for Android as the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I've come up with my own solution to this issue.  I'm sure it's not perfect, but it seems to be working well.  It is partially based on this excellent article...

[Getting the best single location](http://www.andygup.net/html5-geolocation-api-getting-the-best-single-location/)

For my web app, I used an array to capture 50 lat/lng's with an accuracy of less than 11 meters.  After capturing the 50th coordinate, I grab the next lat/lng to be my current position.  I am basically assuming that after checking 50 coordinates with accuracies better than 11 meters, I should have a pretty good idea where I am.

When checking coordinates on indoor WiFi (such as in a gym on a treadmill) the accuracies rarely get near 11 meters, and the array either does not fill up, or it takes a half hour or so to fill.  Even so, by that point my position is pretty stable, and the app will not calculate distance when I'm not actually moving.

When outside using cell towers, the array will fill with 50 coordinates normally in less than 30 seconds.  This means that I lose the first 30 seconds of the persons movement.  But if you're walking or riding a bike, that really isn't missing much.  In the end, my distance measurement may be off by .15 of a mile or such.  I can live with that.

The biggest lesson I've learned is that "getCurrentPostion()" for HTML5 geolocation is basically worthless.  The method simply forces lat/lng coordinates out of the phone, which are usually way off.  In my code I call "updateLocation()" 50 times to collect the coordinates.  In the end, this is much more accurate.

Take some time and read the article posed above.  You'll learn a lot.